# Multi Stage YAML Azure Pipeline Variable Scope

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I am using Multi stage Azure pipelines. Using the Classic editor I am able to set the scope for a variable but using the YAML pipeline I cannot. How is this possible using YAML Multi Stage Pipelines?

[image]

Here is the Classic UI where i can set the scope.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Use a [variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and link the variable group to the desired scope or store secrets in an Azure keyvault or some other secure secret store.

Comment: Ok - so these are really only for "Release" scoped variables?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can, but you have to copy paste the variables in each '- stage' block.

Answer (score 1):

The below method will help. In the below case I am changing in HTML file. You can use config or JSON etc. In HTML file in place of variable declare like

> #{name}#

and

> #{name2}#

```
- stage: Dev
  displayName: Deploy to Dev
  dependsOn: Build
  variables:
    name: valueDev
    name2: valueDev2
  jobs:
    - deployment: Dev
      displayName: Deploy to Dev
      environment: Dev
      strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - checkout: self
                clean: true
              - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
                displayName: 'Replace tokens in **/*.config'
                inputs:
                  targetFiles: '**/*.html'
                  tokenPrefix: '#{'
                  tokenSuffix: '}#'

- stage: Test
      displayName: Deploy to Test
      dependsOn: Dev
      variables:
        name: valueTest
        name2: valueTest2
      jobs:
        - deployment: Test
          displayName: Deploy to Test
          environment: Test
          strategy:
              runOnce:
                deploy:
                  steps:
                  - checkout: self
                    clean: true
                  - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
                    displayName: 'Replace tokens in **/*.config'
                    inputs:
                      targetFiles: '**/*.html'
                      tokenPrefix: '#{'
                      tokenSuffix: '}#'
```